# C# MailMessage string format

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I'm trying to get strings to line up in an email. Everything looks fine when I set the Body of the MailMessage but things aren't lined up when I get the email.

```
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
        //...setup from/to/host/port etc
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        data.AppendLine(string.Format("{0, -20} {1, -20}", "Id:", "26"));
        data.AppendLine(string.Format("{0, -20} {1, -20}", "Name:", "Jeff"));
        // this looks fine in console
        Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());

        email.Body = data.ToString();

        // this looks fine in console
        Console.WriteLine(email.Body);
```

When I get this email it's format is not lined up like email.Body text has it.

Comment: Let me guess: The font is non-proportional (e.g. Arial). Set your mail program to use a monospace font (e.g. Courier New)

Comment: Either use monospace as @ThomasWeller suggested, or use HTML to line things up.

Answer (score 0):

By default body uses `us-ascii` encoding

try using

`email.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

[MSDN Reference for BodyEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.body(v=vs.80).aspx)

NOTE: I haven't tested this is just speculation.

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: What about adding

`email.IsBodyHtml = true;`

Maybe your email provider is treating plain text the way it desires?

Comment: Also make sure to use a monoscaped font.

Comment: It seems if a user can use whatever font they want on their client, then there is nothing I can do around that. I guess HTML but then they have to enable that as well. :/

Comment: Most email viewers support basic HTML by default.